# corona + collision not working

Tags: lua, collision-detection, coronasdk

I am learning Corona and I am trying to use the collision event.
The target of the following program is that the rock is moving towards to the car using transition.to. And print a line to report the collision where it occurs.

However, it does not work. Moreover, I even cannot receive the message "enterenter", what is the reason why the program cannot even get into the enter function?

My code is as follow. Thank you in advance.

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()


local physics = require "physics"
physics.start(); physics.pause()

local function onLocalCollision( self, event )

if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
    print( self.myName .. ": collision began with " .. event.other.myName )

elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
    print( self.myName .. ": collision ended with " .. event.other.myName )
end
end


local widget = require "widget"

function scene:create( event )
print("entercreate")
local sceneGroup = self.view

local backgrd = display.newImage("background2.png",0,260)
backgrd:scale(3,3)
local car = display.newImage("car2.png",80,270)
physics.addBody(car,"static")
car.myName="Car"

local rock = display.newImage("rock.jpg",520,280)
rock:scale(0.05,0.05)
physics.addBody(rock,"static")
rock.myName="rock"


sceneGroup:insert(backgrd)
sceneGroup:insert(car)
sceneGroup:insert(rock)
transition.to(backgrd,{time=24000, x=-1800,onComplete=endScroll})
transition.to(rock,{time=4000, delay=2500,x=-40})
end

function scene:enter( event )
print("enterenter")
physics.start()
local sceneGroup = self.view
Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onLocalCollision )
end



scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "enter", scene )


return scene
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code with a local and a global (Runtime) listener:

```
local widget = require "widget"
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()

local physics = require "physics"
physics.start()
physics.setGravity( 0,0 )

local function onGlobalCollision( event )
        local target = event.object1
        local other = event.object2

        if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
            print( "GLOBAL: " .. target.name .. ": collision began with " .. other.name )
        elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
            print( "GLOBAL: " .. target.name .. ": collision ended  with " .. other.name )      
        end
    end

local function onLocalCollision( event )
    local target = event.target
    local other = event.other

    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
        print( "LOCAL: " .. other.name .. ": collision began with " .. target.name )
    elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
        print( "LOCAL: " .. other.name .. ": collision ended  with " .. target.name )       
    end
end

function scene:create( event )
    print("scene:create")


    local sceneGroup = self.view

    local car = display.newRect( 100, 100, 100, 100 )
    car.name = "car"
    physics.addBody( car )

    local rock = display.newRect( 250, 250, 100, 100 )
    rock.name = "rock"
    rock:setFillColor( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 )
    physics.addBody( rock )
    rock:addEventListener( "collision", onLocalCollision )

    sceneGroup:insert(car)
    sceneGroup:insert(rock)

    transition.to(rock,{time=4000, x = -40, y = -100})

    Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onGlobalCollision )
end

function scene:enter( event )
    print("scene:enter")    
    local sceneGroup = self.view

end

scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "enter", scene )


return scene
```

The problem that you have with your code is that the two bodies are static and two static bodies can't collide with each other and that there is nothing called `scene:enter` in composer (so that's why it doesn't gets called and therefor not the `onLocalListener`).

> Some body types will — or will not — collide with other body types. In
>   a collision between two physical objects, at least one of the objects
>   must be dynamic, since this is the only body type which collides with
>   any other type. See the Physics Bodies guide for details on body
>   types.

https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/physics/collisionDetection/index.html

Here is some information about the Composer API and you'll that you should probably use `scene:show`:
https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/01/21/introducing-the-composer-api-plus-tutorial/